# App is crashing after trying to show a UIAlert if the user hasn't granted permission for notifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I have the following code, which is designed to ask permission to send notifications to the user and then if they don't grant permission, the app gives them a warning in the form of a UIAlert - this is because on the previous screen they selected if they want notifications and the time they want them, and therefore it wouldn't make sense for them to not give permission here.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in

    if !granted {
        let permissionNotGrantedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Notifications not enabled", message: "We won't be able to send you notifications.\n\nYou can allow us to send you notifications from your device's settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        permissionNotGrantedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings", style: .default, handler: { action in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        }))
        permissionNotGrantedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        }))
        self.present(permissionNotGrantedAlert, animated: true)
    }

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the app runs, this exception is thrown:

```
Exception: "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."
```

And this error message is shown in the console:

```
[Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behaviour.
```

How can I go about displaying a UIAlert if permission is not granted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(permissionNotGrantedAlert, animated: true)
}
```